# What values will I use for circle-to-land in categories A and B? RVR 1800m or RVR 2200m?

Tags: terminology, aeronautical-charts, jeppesen, visibility, minimums

What values will I use for circle-to-land in categories A and B? RVR 1800m or RVR 2200m? And if I am using them, why are the visibility values such as 1500m-1600m determined?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you can do a circling approach, you must do either a either CDFA straight in, or a non-CDFA approach to runway 22, and then circle to land on a different runway.

The circling minimum are dependant on which straight-in approach you conduct, and also dependant on the availability of ALS lighting:

| Appr. CAT | CDFA | ALS | MDA | Vis. / RVR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | yes |  | 1100' | 1500m |
| B | yes |  | 1100' | 1600m |
| A | no | yes | 1100' | 1800m |
| B | no | yes | 1100' | 1800m |
| A | no | no | 1100' | 2200m |
| B | no | no | 1100' | 2200m |

Comment: Thank you for the tabular reply, captain. I missed that I had to do a straight-in-landing approach first to be able to circle-to-land. But the phrase "approach lights have no effect on circling minimums" in the Jeppesen Manual confuses me. Does "minimums" here represent 1100 feet of MDA? I would be very happy if you reply. (I've attached the image of the expression in Jeppesen to the question.)

Comment: That confuses me as well. “Minimums” includes ceiling and visibility. Maybe someone else here might know the answer.

Comment: I think what is meant here is the following: Whether there is ALS in direct approach or not affects the RVR or visibility value, but there is no such distinction for circle-to-land. When we look at the circle-to-land section, we see that there is no separate MDA for lighting. That's how I interpreted it, captain, what do you think?

Comment: I understand the 1st note given as follows: Since we will make a straight-in landing approach before making a circle-to-land, we also need to take into account the lighting systems that affect the straight-in landing minimum values. However, this is a situation that we will only evaluate when the circle-to-land visibility or RVR value is lower than the straight-in landing values. It would be my pleasure if you approve my interpretation, captain.